How do you get a job to run a conditional if + require a job to run first in github actions
I am trying to figure out how to add to my conditions at the top level. Basically I want to run job-run-all and job-run-suite no matter what happens with job-delete-data. But I need job-delete-data to run first.
I also only want to run job-run-all and job-run-suite with a certain conditional but it seems to always skip them if I use always + my conditional
name: Run Automation On Demand

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      choice:
        type: choice
        description: Which suite do you want to run?
        options:
        - All Tests
        - All UI
        - All API
        - Login
      DeleteOldData:
        type: boolean
        required: false
        default: false

jobs:
  job-delete-data:

    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.DeleteOldData == 'true' }}
    run: blah blah

  job-run-all:
    needs: job-delete-data
    if: |
      always() &&
      ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }}


    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [21.x]

    steps:
    - name: If All Tests, Run All Playwright Tests in Parallel
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }}
      run: xxxx

  job-run-suite:
    needs: job-delete-data
    if: |
      always()
      ${{ github.event.inputs.choice != 'All Tests' }}

    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [21.x]

    steps:
    - name: If Suite Specific, Run Just Selected Suite
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice != 'All Tests' && github.event.inputs.choice != 'All UI' && github.event.inputs.choice != 'All API' }}
      run: URL=${{ github.event.inputs.URL }} npx playwright test --workers=8 --grep @${{ github.event.inputs.choice }}
      

I expect that the job job-run-suite is skipped if my condition is not true but basically it always skips it no matter what
